# Self Association ActiveRecord Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, self-reference, ancestry

In **Rails 4.2.6** I have a model Model **Car** where I would like to have its descendants as association

We are using, **ancestry** gem, for this and it gives descendants as named scope.

So I tried like this,

```
  has_many :tesla, lambda{ |object|
    where("ancestry LIKE %#{object.id}/%")
  }, class_name: :Car, foreign_key: :ancestry
```

But no help, Can anyone help on this, I would like to have this as association, where I can have the association interfaces like includes, preload, etc..

Comment: Try class_name: "Car"

Also, is ancestry and id field? If so, foreign_key: :ancestry_id ? Haven't worked with ancestry but maybe that helps?

Comment: @sump: we tried class name Car & yes both of them are fields, also if I keep foreign key as ancestry_id it will be a straight equality check but we want "LIKE" to be used